# in class project totally stuck, visual basic intro course half way done

Tags: visual-studio-2010

The teacher is very tough and unhelpful in this class. I have tried my best to keep up but fell behind and need a good score on this in class assignment can anyone help me? I ahae asked tons of questions stayed after and used the tutor but apperently im a terrible programmer. just need to pass this class because im in networking but its required. Working on flow chart and psuedo as we speak if anyone could even just get me started its such a simple program im just messed up on my fundamentals.

Build a console program that requests the user’s birthday and outputs the top selling album from the year they were born.  The list of the top selling albums is listed below.

Input file: final.txt

```
1956       Calypso               

1957       My Fair Lady      

1958       My Fair Lady      

1959       Music from Peter Gunn               

1960       The Sound of Music       

1961       Camelot              

1962       West Side Story               

1963       West Side Story               

1964       Hello, Dolly!       

1965       Mary Poppins   

1966       Whipped Cream & Other Delights           

1967       More of The Monkees 

1968       Are You Experienced?   

1969       In-A-Gadda-Da-Vida      

1970       Bridge Over Troubled Water       

1971       Jesus Christ Superstar   

1972       Harvest               

1973       The World Is a Ghetto   

1974       Goodbye Yellow Brick Road        

1975       Elton John's Greatest Hits           

1976       Frampton Comes Alive 

1977       Rumours             
 1978       Saturday Night Fever    

1979       52nd Street                       

1980       The Wall              

1981       Hi Infidelity        

1982       Asia       

1983       Thriller 

1984       Thriller 

1985       Born in the U.S.A.           

1986       Whitney Houston           

1987       Slippery When Wet        

1988       Faith     

1989       Don't Be Cruel  

1990       Janet Jackson's Rhythm Nation

1991       Ropin' The Wind              

1992       Some Gave All  

1993       The Bodyguard

1994       The Lion King    

1995       Cracked Rear View         

1996       Jagged Little Pill               

1997       Spice    

1998       Titanic  

1999       Millennium
```

The following prompt should be used.

Please enter your birthdate (MM-DD-YY) “End” to finish:

When the program is finished an output file needs to be written.  The file should contain: the number of searches performed and a list of the years searched.

Compress the project file, flowchart, psuedo code and output and Upload it

This is how far I have made it.

```
Sub Main()

    Try
        Dim albums As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
        Dim response As String = String.Empty
        Dim searches As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
        Dim year As Integer = 0

        Using reader As New System.IO.StreamReader("E:\IntroProgramming\FinalProject\Final.txt")
            While Not reader.EndOfStream
                albums.Add(reader.ReadLine())
            End While
        End Using

        While response.ToUpper() <> "END"
            Console.Write("Please enter your birthdate (MM-DD-YY) ""End"" to finish: ")
            response = Console.ReadLine()
            If (Integer.TryParse(response.Substring(response.Length - 2), year)) Then
                If (year >= 56 And year <= 99) Then
                    searches.Add("19" & response.Substring(response.Length - 2))
                    Console.WriteLine("The best selling album for the year 19" & year.ToString() & " was " & albums(year - 56))
                Else
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid year! Please try again")
                End If
            End If
        End While

        Using writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter("finaloutput.txt", False)
            writer.WriteLine("There were a total of " & searches.Count.ToString() & " valid searches")
            For Each s As String In searches
                writer.WriteLine(s)
                Console.ReadLine()
            Next



        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Module

Everything is working except the when you enter End to finish  it is not outputing number of searches and list of years searched.

Comment: What part are you having a problem with or you do you just want someone to do all the work for you?

Comment: We need to see at least some of your own code first. We can help correct mistakes, but we don't usually start from scratch for you.

Comment: well I have done these io files before just performing processes I have done loops arrays ect but never had to take input and run it through a txt file like this not sure where to start or if this even needs a loop. i assume it does because you need to enter end to finish but im jsut confused how to make it work. Even a flow chart would be amazing i can figure out the code.

Comment: im just panicking cause i have 3 hours to complete, 2 hours left now it im working on it now ill post once I have some code, was starting with the flow chart almsot done

Comment: I just finished the flow chart of what I think needs to be done tryuing ti figure out how to attach it lol

Comment: i beleive I just added a hyperlink to my flow chart at the top of question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Main()
    Try
        Dim albums As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
        Dim response As String = String.Empty
        Dim searches As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
        Dim year As Integer = 0

        Using reader As New System.IO.StreamReader("final.txt")
            While Not reader.EndOfStream
                albums.Add(reader.ReadLine())
            End While
        End Using

        While response.ToUpper() <> "END"
            Console.Write("Please enter your birthdate (MM-DD-YY) ""End"" to finish: ")
            response = Console.ReadLine()
            If (Integer.TryParse(response.Substring(response.Length - 2), year)) Then
                If (year >= 56 And year <= 99) Then
                    searches.Add("19" & response.Substring(response.Length - 2))
                    Console.WriteLine("The best selling album for the year 19" & year.ToString() & " was " & albums(year - 56))
                Else
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid year! Please try again")
                End If
            End If
        End While

        Using writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter("finaloutput.txt", False)
            writer.WriteLine("There were a total of " & searches.Count.ToString() & " valid searches")
            For Each s As String In searches
                writer.WriteLine(s)
            Next
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm using an old trick here. Since the numbers are a sequential block, we can offset inside the array: year - 56 gives us the offset we need.

Comment: i will try thanks jsut finished and linked my flow chart of what i thought eneded to be done

Comment: most of it looks good but when i run it it just flashes and disappears can only make out some erros but a good start will have to play with it. Much different approach then I had considered.

Comment: think maybe i need a blank readline so i have a chance to read the message hehe

Comment: You need to put the "final.txt" input file in the same folder where the executable is. That may be the problem.

Comment: ok yah that fixed it but the error is its not finding the txt file must be worded wrong when its calling it

Comment: yah i did do that but its still acting up ill play with it a bit

Comment: regardless thanks a ton this will save me loads of time from here on

Comment: this is a homework assignment from last week thats similiar and pulls up file fine do i need to perhaps be more specific with file path

Comment: wont fit here ill try to add it to post

Comment: woohoo got it! had to be more specific with file path lol I r not smart thanks a ton.

Comment: meh it accepts dates and print proper song and year which is awesome but it does not output  number of searches and listof years searched

Comment: It should be in a file called finaloutput.txt; it won't print to the screen as that was not the specification. The spec called for an output file to contain that data.

Comment: thats true man think we got it then guess i read it wrong thanks again so very much

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know VB very well (C#/C++ for me) but to help you out here is a basic little program to get you started.  I am sure this isn't the most efficient way, as every bit of this was thrown together just by searching the internet on how to do things.  But it will get you going in the right direction.  If you need to write to a file you can look up StreamWriter and there will be tons of stuff there for you, can't do it all for ya :)

```
Sub Main()
    'this is the first part for you
    Dim szBirthDate As String
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your birthdate (MM-DD-YY) ""Enter""to finish:")
    szBirthDate = Console.ReadLine()
    Dim szInputtedDateArray As Array
    Dim szYear As String
    szInputtedDateArray = szBirthDate.Split("-")
    szYear = "19" & szInputtedDateArray(2).ToString()

    'at this point the szYear variable has the year format from your final.txt file

    'now read the file until you find your year
    Try
        ' Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file. 
        Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\appdev\final.txt")
        Dim line As String
        Dim cnt As Integer
        cnt = 0

        ' Read the file until you find the year you need or the end of the file is reached. 
        Do
            cnt += 1
            line = sr.ReadLine()
            line = line.Trim()
            If line.IndexOf(szYear, 0, 4) > -1 Then
                Console.WriteLine("In " + szYear.ToString() + " the best seller was " + line.Substring(5))
                Console.WriteLine(cnt.ToString() + " items searched")
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop Until line Is Nothing
        sr.Close()
    Catch E As Exception
        ' Let the user know what went wrong.
        Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:")
        Console.WriteLine(E.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

As I said above, I'm not a VB guy so this may be crude but it works, familiarize yourself with it and you remember the internet is your friend.

Comment: much appreciated with the combined effort I at least have half a working program a perfect flow chart and psuedo code so ill still pass the class with a B and move on in my networking career lol thanks a bunch!